# How do I calculate the cv for observation errors from a time series of actual values and a time series of values with observation error?

Tags: coefficient-of-variation

I have a time series of actual values.

I also have a time series consisting of values with observation error.

Assuming that the observation errors are normally distributed, independent of one another and are proportional to the actual values,  how can I calculate the coefficient of variation for the observation errors?